# Should XSD occurrence bounds be on the sequence or the element?

Tags: xml, xsd

If I have an element with one or more subelements, should the min/maxoccurs attributes be on the xsd:sequence element, the xsd:element, both, or neither?

```
<xsd:element name="books">
  <xsd:complexType>
    <xsd:sequence minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded"> <!-- here? -->
      <xsd:element ref="book" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded"/> <!-- or here? -->
    </xsd:sequence>
  </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:element>
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

In almost all circumstances, you want to put the min/max Occurs on the element within a sequence and not on the sequence.  Using your example:

```
<xsd:element name="books">
  <xsd:complexType>
    <xsd:sequence>
      <xsd:element ref="book" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
    </xsd:sequence>
  </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:element>
```

This is unequivocal.  If you have a series of book elements in a row, you can point to exactly which schema item is producing them.  However:

```
<xsd:element name="books">
  <xsd:complexType>
    <xsd:sequence minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
      <xsd:element ref="book" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
    </xsd:sequence>
  </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:element>
```

Here, if you have two "`book`" elements in a row, do you have two `sequence`s in a row, or one `sequence` with two `book` elements?  This fails the [Unique Particle Attribution](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-1/#cos-nonambig) requirement.

Finally, if you put the min/max Occurs on the sequence and you later add an additional element:

```
<xsd:element name="books">
  <xsd:complexType>
    <xsd:sequence minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
      <xsd:element ref="book"/>
      <xsd:element ref="ebook"/>
    </xsd:sequence>
  </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:element>
```

then this may allow the following XML, which is probably not what you intend:

```
<books>
  <book/><ebook/><book/><ebook/><book/><ebook/><book/><ebook/>
</books>
```

whereas if you have:

```
<xsd:element name="books">
  <xsd:complexType>
    <xsd:sequence/>
      <xsd:element ref="book" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
      <xsd:element ref="ebook" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
    </xsd:sequence>
  </xsd:complexType>
</xsd:element>
```

then it is clear and unambiguous what you intend:  A sequence of one or more `book` elements followed by a sequence of one or more `ebook` elements.

Answer (score 2):

It should be on the `<xsd:element>`, IMHO.

The effect of putting it on the sequence is the same, eventually (for this case). But looking at it from a logical perspective, you want to express that it is a *sequence of elements*, and not *a row of sequences containing one element each*.

Putting it on both would definitely feel wrong for me, though for this case it would (again) make no practical difference.

Answer (score 1):

Put the maxOccurs attribute on the <xsd:element> element.

```
<xsd:sequence>
  <xsd:element ref="book" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded"/> <!-- here! -->
</xsd:sequence>
```